# Specified object from JSONObject

Tags: java, json, gson

I have `JSONObject` which contains as shown below and created class `Markets` contained all fields. I want put `JSONObject` elements to created object of `Markets`.

Example: `Markets markets = new Markets()`,then put elements from `JSONObject` to `markets` and I want to be able to get `markets.getInstrumentName()`. How can I do this ?

I try using `Gson`, like this `Markets markets = gson2.fromJson(jsonObject, Markets.class);` but there are different types and it is wrong way.

`JSONObject`:

```
{
  "map": {
    "netChange": -81.0,
    "instrumentType": "INDICES",
    "percentageChange": -1.31,
    "scalingFactor": 1,
    "epic": "IX.D.FTSE.DAILY.IP",
    "updateTime": "00:02:48",
    "updateTimeUTC": "23:02:48",
    "offer": 6095.8,
    "instrumentName": "FTSE 100",
    "high": 6188.3,
    "low": 6080.8,
    "streamingPricesAvailable": true,
    "marketStatus": "TRADEABLE",
    "delayTime": 0,
    "expiry": "DFB",
    "bid": 6094.8
  }
}
```

`Markets`:

```
class Markets {
    private double bid;
    private double offer;
    private int delayTime;
    private String epic;
    private String expiry;
    private double high;
    private double low;
    private String instrumentName;
    private String instrumentType;
    private String marketStatus;
    private double netChange;
    private double percentageChange;
    private int scalingFactor;
    private boolean streamingPricesAvailable;
    private String updateTime;
    private String updateTimeUTC;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Did you read the [fancy manual](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)? It's full of examples.

Comment: I read basic documentation.

Comment: You probably need a "Map" class with one field of type Markets and named map, if that's your difficulty

Comment: I want all data from `JSONObject` in my `Markets` class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Jackson library

```
JSONObject jsonObject = //...
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Markets markets = mapper.readValue(jsonObject.toString(), Markets.class);
```

Comment: I need the same using `Gson`

Comment: Have you tried this ?

      `Markets markets = new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), Markets.class); `

Comment: Yes it works, I forgot write `jsonObject.toString()` the `.toString()` was needed ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample Code when you want to convert JSON to object :

```
yourObject = new Gson().fromJson(yourJSONObject.toString(), YourObject.class);
```

I'm using Gson 2.4. and it works fine.

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
```